# How to save B+ Tree in a file using JAVA

Tags: java, save

I want to save B+ Tree in a file using JAVA.
First, I used Serialization. However, if the Height of tree is big, Stackoverflow occured.
Is there any method to save B+ Tree in a file?

Comment: Show what you have tried and the problems you faced.

Answer (score 0):

If your B+ Tree height is large enough that this causes a stack overflow, then there is something wrong with the way you have implemented it.  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree#Characteristics), the characteristics of a B+ tree include that its height is logarithmic on the number of the number of records that it holds.

At any rate, most standard serialization implementations will struggle if you give them a very deep data structure.

However, you could implement your own tree-walker for your B+ tree that *avoids* recursion, and use that as the starting point for a serializer.  It would all be custom code though; i.e. you would need to write it yourself.  Start by searching for *"non-recursive tree walk"*.